# ASP.NET Controls after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page which consists a few asp:buttons, asp:textbox, gridview and asp:imagebutton.

When the Page loads for the first time, the user insert a number into the textbox, and then presses the button which preform the postback.

My question is that : after the postback in the page_load event I have a refrence to the imagebutton, i can set its display etc.

As apart of the postback, the gridview is being updated, i call gridview.databind() from the page_load 
so the gridview selecting event is triggred, but when i try to refernce the imagebutton from whithin the selecting method i see that the imagebutton is null.

If i will try to refrence that imagebutton again from the page_load, after the selecting method is completed, there is no problem.

Why cant I reference the imagebutton, or actually any other control, from the selecting method ?

10X alot :)

Comment: By "selecting event" do you mean the OnSelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: I tried to answer, but I'm not fully understanding the question. Can you post some code?

Comment: The selecting event of the datasource which the gridview is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using page load for both postback and pageLoad()
Try using `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { //your code }` for setting initial controls

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question properly, on your Page_Load you need to do something like this

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        //Do your initial binding for the image
    }
}
```

Then in your button event you can rebind the image to whatever new image you like

Comment: I can Reference the button from the page_load, that I know.

My question is why within the selecting method of the gridview, which trigrred by the databind from the page_load, the controls of the page are all NULL.